# How can a method know of a Selenium object, without object being declared? C#

Tags: c#, selenium

This code is created by firefox selenium:

```
[Test]
    public void TheNB1UnitTest()
    {
        driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(baseURL + "/Login");
        driver.FindElement(By.Id("Group")).Clear();
    }

    private bool IsElementPresent(By by)
    {
        try
        {
            driver.FindElement(by);
            return true;
        }
        catch (NoSuchElementException)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Given that `By` is an object from the class `org.openqa.selenium package`, how is `IsElementPresent(By by)` even making use of it with regards to  `driver.FindElement(By.Id("Group")).Clear();` ??

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by ''even making use of it with regards to driver.FindElement(By.Id("Group")).Clear(); ??" Do you mean because you are not declaring it as a `new` object?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look in the [source code of C# binding of Selenium](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/dotnet/src/webdriver/By.cs)

You will find the method definition for `By.Id()`, it is a `static` method:

```
public static By Id(string idToFind)
```

maybe that already answers your question? Because the method is `static` you don't need to "declare" anything.

and in this method you will find this line:

```
By by = new By();
```

so there is indeed a "new" object created and handed over to your `IsElementPresent()` method.

Answer (score 0):

You can set a breakpoint in IsElementPresent to see when it is called. However in this case I guess the IsElementPresent is generated, but not used till you make some assert which use the IsElementPresent.

The IsElementPresent is generated for you to make asserts in your unit test:

```
public void TheNB1UnitTest()
{
    driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(baseURL + "/Login");
    driver.FindElement(By.Id("Group")).Clear();

    Assert.IsTrue(IsElementPresent(By.<my search>));
}
```

[after-generating-webdriver-code-how-and-where-to-modify-code](http://www.scriptscoop.net/t/f6839fdbbcc1/java-after-generating-webdriver-code-how-and-where-to-modify-code.html)